# How to go around VboxManage runtime error?

Tags: virtualbox

VirtualBox 6.1.18, Host OS Windows 10 Pro, Guest OS Windows 10 Pro.

Intention: Generate a VMDK version of a VDI filesystem file.

Command:

```
vboxmanage clonehd --format VMDK W10MyDisk.vdi W10MyDisk.vmdk
```

After some minutes, response:

```
0%...10%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR
VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to clone medium
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not create the clone medium 'E:\Users\Alex\VirtualBox\W10Doutorado\W10Doutorado.vmdk' (VERR_IO_CRC)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleCloneMedium(struct HandlerArg *)" at line 1071 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp
```

What to do to go around the problem and finnish the clonning process?

Comment: Sometimes this means a corrupted file. Run perhaps `chkdsk` on the host.

Comment: Could be a corrupt ISO, or a faulty HDD. Try enabling the Host I/O Cache option, in the VM settings -> Storage -> Controller SATA

Comment: @harrymc that was a goog idea, but disk test returned no errors. However, a file test performed by 7Zip returned 3 CRC errors. Any ideas from now on?

Comment: @spikey_richie i did it, but nothing changed, The problem is that when the VM boots, Windows is loaded and the desktop is shown, but the VBox window freezes,

Answer (score 1):

You have CRC errors on the disk, which means that the disk is failing.
Save your data and get another disk, in the hope that you have backups.

If you absolutely need to
recover the data, perhaps try again after the disk has cooled down.
You could also try to see if the old
[Roadkil's Unstoppable Copier](https://roadkil.net/program.php/P29/Unstoppable%20Copier)
still works in Windows 10. See the
[documentation](https://www.roadkil.net/support.php?AppID=Unstoppable%20Copier&VersionID=5.2)
for more information.

If none of the above has worked for you and if the lost data is very important,
professional recovery services do exist, but they are costly.

Comment: The CRC error happens only when testing the vdi file. Disk surface tests do not return any evidence of HD problem. I'm looking for a way to recover the vdi file.

Comment: Disk hard errors are difficult to recover. A method that worked for some is to cool down the disk in deep-freeze, protected in a plastic bag from humidity and with some anti-humidity sachets, for a few hours, then try to copy the data quickly. But I take no responsibility for the results.

Answer (score 1):

`VERR_IO_CRC` is related to disk problems.

I ran the following:

`chkdsk /f /r d:`

```
/f    Fixes errors on the disk
/r    Locates bad sectors and recovers readable information
```

and afterwards `vboxmanage` commands worked fine.

If the drive is particularly damaged, I find the following usually helps:

Boot Linux and run:

`badblocks -nsv /dev/device -o badblocks.txt`

```
-n    non-destructive read-write mode
-s    show progress
-v    verbpse
```

This writes to each byte on the drive (without losing data) which typically forces the drive to realise there are errors.

If you see bad blocks on a modern hard drive or SSD, it's generally a sign that the drive may be failing. While drives do have spare blocks that they can remap to (automatically) when they detect a block going bad, by the time you're seeing them, it means those spare blocks might have been exhausted.